# Nested routing is not working in React Router dom V4 from individual component and works only from App.js component

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to implement nested routing in my React app, but 'Route' only works when used in App.js and doesnot works when 'Route' is used in another component.Only blank page appears. When checked in React Developer tool, the 'match' object is coming as 'null'.

I need to pass some props from  'MovieDetail' component to 'RTest' component but it is not routing from MovieDetail component. Only option left is to Lift the state up to App.js. But I need the solution for Nested routing.

When I uncomment the 'Route' for 'rTest' in App.js, the app works fine. Please help.

Below is the snippet from app follwed by files.

[image: Movie Detail Component having]

[image: Blank Screen on click of link. React Developer tool showing match object as null]

After uncommenting 'Route' for 'rTest' in App.js, app works fine.
[image: RTest component appear successfully when is moved to App.js]

App.js file when Route component is commented for 'RTest component'

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
 import MovieDetail from "./components/navComponents/movieDetails";
import RTest from "./components/navComponents/rTest";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    // products: [ { id: 1, name: 'Product 1' }, { id: 2, name: 'Product 2' }, { id: 3, name: 'Product 3' } ]
  card: [],
        pageSize: 6,
        currentPage: 1,
        cartItems: []
};

render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Navigation></Navigation>
       
        <div className="content">
          <Switch>
           
            <Route path="/catalouge" render={(props)=>
              <Catalouge 
              pageSize={this.state.pageSize} 
              {...props}
              catImages={this.state.card}
              onAddApp={this.handleAdd}
              onSubApp={this.handleSub}
              onCartAddApp={this.handleCartAdd}
              >
              </Catalouge>}>

              </Route>
            <Route path="/login" component={Login}></Route>
            <Route path="/toCart" 
            render={(props)=>
            <ShoppingCart cartItems={this.state.cartItems} {...props}></ShoppingCart>} />
            <Route path="/posts" component={Posts}></Route>
            <Route path="/customers" component={Customers}></Route>
            <Route path="/movies" component={Movies}></Route>
            <Route path="/movie/details" exact component={(props) => <MovieDetail {...props} />} />
            {/* <Route path="/rTest" component={RTest} /> */}
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

MovieDetail component is below:

```html
   
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import RTest from './rTest';

const MovieDetail = ({ match }) => {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <h1>Hello MovieDetial</h1>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <Link to="/rTest">rTest</Link>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <Route path="/rTest" component={RTest} />
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};

export default MovieDetail;
```

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const RTest = (props) => {
    return <h1>Hello RTest</h1>;
};

export default RTest;
```

```
package.json file is below
```

{
"name": "router-app",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.16",
"axios": "^0.18.1",
"bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
"font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
"joi-browser": "^13.4.0",
"react": "^16.4.1",
"react-dom": "^16.14.0",
"react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
"react-scripts": "1.1.4",
"reactstrap": "^9.0.1"
},
"scripts": {
"start": "react-scripts start",
"build": "react-scripts build",
"test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
"eject": "react-scripts eject"
}
}

=================================================

Answer (score 0):

***Please App.js file.***

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
 import MovieDetail from "./components/navComponents/movieDetails";
import RTest from "./components/navComponents/rTest";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    // products: [ { id: 1, name: 'Product 1' }, { id: 2, name: 'Product 2' }, { id: 3, name: 'Product 3' } ]
  card: [],
        pageSize: 6,
        currentPage: 1,
        cartItems: []
};

render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Navigation></Navigation>
       
        <div className="content">
          <Switch>
           
            <Route path="/catalouge" render={(props)=>
              <Catalouge 
              pageSize={this.state.pageSize} 
              {...props}
              catImages={this.state.card}
              onAddApp={this.handleAdd}
              onCartAddApp={this.handleCartAdd}
              >
              </Catalouge>}>

              </Route>
            <Route path="/login" component={Login}></Route>
            <Route path="/toCart" 
            render={(props)=>
            <ShoppingCart cartItems={this.state.cartItems} {...props}></ShoppingCart>} />
            <Route path="/posts" component={Posts}></Route>
            <Route path="/customers" component={Customers}></Route>
            <Route path="/movies" component={Movies}></Route>
            <Route path="/movie/details" exact component={(props) => <MovieDetail {...props} />} />
            {/* <Route path="/rTest" component={RTest} /> */}
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: App.js file is provided. Below is the line of code which shows the Route as commented for 'rTest'.

<Route path="/movie/details" exact component={(props) => <MovieDetail {...props} />} />
            {/* <Route path="/rTest" component={RTest} /> */}
          </Switch>